# Derivations with inequalities

Tags: analysis, inequality

I have following statements

$$\dot{c}(x) \geq -\beta(x)$$
$$\dot{c}(x) = \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} (f(x)+g(x)u)$$
$$|\hat{f}(x)-f(x)| \leq d(x)$$

I am working and something and not sure if I am allowed to do following:
$$-|\hat{f}(x)-f(x)| \geq -d(x)$$
$$\dot{c}(x) =\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} (f(x)-\hat{f}(x)+\hat{f}(x)+g(x)u) +\beta(x) \geq \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} (-d+\hat{f}(x)+g(x)u) +\beta(x)$$

Comment: forgot too type in latex @amWhy

Comment: No, actually, you did well with latex.

Comment: the rest is fine? @amWhy

Comment: @elsa Please do not vandalize posted questions, including your own. Rolled back.

Comment: Please *do not* vandalize your post in a way that renders the answer provided incorrect or meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement is correct since $x \le y \iff -x \ge -y$. (As a very simple example, $2 \le 3 \iff -2 \ge -3$.)

However, the statement about the derivative need not hold true. Ultimately what you're claiming is that if

$$f(x) \le g(x)$$

near the point of differentiation, then

$$f'(x) \le g'(x)$$

(At least, that's your claim boiled down to its essence: that derivatives preserve inequalities.) This obviously need not hold. Consider, for example, the functions

$$f(x) = x^2 \qquad g(x) = x^3$$

at the point $x = 1/2$. We see that

$$\frac 1 8 = g \left( \frac 1 2 \right) < f \left( \frac 1 2 \right) = \frac 1 4$$

but we have $f'(x) = 2x$ and $g'(x) = 3x^2$, so

$$\frac 3 4 = g'\left( \frac 1 2 \right) \not < f' \left( \frac 1 2 \right) = \frac 1 2$$

(And this should make sense. We can translate a function vertically without changing the slopes tangent to it - and that's what the derivative is, the slope of tangent lines. Thus we could obtain whatever set of inequalities we want for $f,g$: $f \le g, f < g, f > g, f\ge g$, but the derivatives would remain unchanged.)